# Losing Hyperlinks when converting PPT to PDF using Adobe Acrobat Pro 

Tags: pdf, conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, adobe-acrobat

When I use Adobe Acrobot Pro 9.0 to create PDF from a PPT file, the hyperlinks in the generated PDF don't work (unless I have http://... in the hyperlink text)!

I have checked the setting and "Add links to Adobe PDF file" is selected.
Any idea why it is not working and how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I think a very simple solution for you might be a virtual pdf printer, such as [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/). I'm sure Acrobat Pro is much more efficient and has more features, but for the specific issue you have it might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do : `libreoffice --invisible --convert-to pdf file1.ppt file2.ppt ...`

Comment: Since PowerPoint is the only application that can reliably read PPT files, it would be best to save the PPT as an ODP from within PowerPoint.

Comment: But, in my case, I had a bunch of .ppt and LibreOffice did the job well.

Comment: Yea, I guess if LibreOffice can handle it all on its own, then that's obviously easier. But I just mean in general you'll get more reliable results if you have PowerPoint save it in ODP first, especially if you're noticing compatibility problems with the PPT in other apps like the question poster is having with Acrobat.